# Correct pronunciation of $\in$.

Tags: notation, pronunciation

I was curious whether there is a standard reference for the correct English pronunciation of general mathematical symbols. In particular, I am wondering how to pronounce the symbol "$\in$" correctly, or at least what is most common.

In mathematical texts, I have seen phrases like "Let $x \in X$ such that" and "Let $x \in X$ be such that". In the first phrase $\in$ seems to be pronounced as "be an element of", whereas the correct pronunciation in the second phrase is just "in".

In the excellent survey *How to write mathematics?*, Paul Halmos writes that he prefers to read "$\in"$ as "is in" rather than the preposition "in". This still seems to be very personal, so I am curious whether there is a standard nowadays.

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ code for $\in$ is ``\in``. This gives a clue.

Comment: Whatever makes sense linguistically, tbh.  If we write "Let $x \in X$", we'd read "Let $x$ be an element of $X$", whereas if we write "Suppose $x \in X$", we'd read "Suppose $x$ is an element of $X$" or even "Suppose $x$ is in $X$".  The symbol "$\in$" is a placeholder for an idea; it doesn't particularly matter how the idea is expressed as long as it is.

Comment: @ClementC. Then should $\oint$ be pronounced as "oint"?

Comment: @HenryW. Devil's advocate? When the grammar is **clearly** linked to the semantics (\in, \to, \subset, \notin, \mapsto), taking it as a clue for the pronunciation makes sense. (That's also why using  ``\to`` when writing $f\colon X\to Y$, instead of the identically-looking ``\rightarrow``, is a good idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few idiomatic usages.  I'll copy from a randomly-selected textbook on my shelf.  This is from a proof of Cantor's Theorem: For every set $A$, $A$ and its power set $\mathscr{P}(A)$ do not have the same size:

> Let $f \colon A \to \mathscr{P}(A)$ be given.  We will show that $f$ is not onto.  Define $$ B = \left\{ x\in A \mid x \notin f(x) \right\}$$  Since $B \subseteq A$, this means that $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ [1], so $B$ is a member of the codomain of $f$.  To see that $f(x) \neq B$ for all $x \in A$ [2], we imagine what would happen if there were a $b\in A$ with $f(b) = B$.  A contradiction then arises when considering the question “Is $b\in B$? [3]” ...

From *Discrete Mathematics: Mathematical Reasoning and Proof with Puzzles, Patterns, and Games*, by Douglas E. Ensley and J. Winston Cawley.

In the first note “this means that $B\in\mathscr{P}(A)$,” we can read $\in$ as “is in.” It would be equivalent to say “this means that $B$ is in $\mathscr{P}(A)$.”  The main idea of the sentence is that the relation holds.

In the second, “$f(x) \neq B$ for all $x \in A$”, the $\in$ can be read as just “in.”  As in, “$f(x) \neq B$ for all $x$ in $A$.”  To put “is” in there would insert an extra verb.  The relation $x\in A$ is not the main idea here; it's  parenthetical to $f(x) \neq B$.

In the third, the relation is still the main idea of the clause, but to make the question start with a verb (standard written English), we write *is* and read “in” for $\in$.